# Do we need the e1000e tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Against my better judgement I actually approved this [edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/421410) and I wasn't given the option to edit it further. It was my intent to add "Intel Linux Base Driver for Gigabit Ethernet controllers" to at least flesh it out a bit, but in retrospect I'm not convinced that we need a specific tag for every driver on the planet. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. We don't need a tag for every network driver, that's meta information. I've gone ahead and removed the tag.

Note that the edit in question was made to the tag wiki *excerpt*, not the wiki itself. The excerpt is used to briefly explain how a tag should be used, including what questions to put it on and, if necessary, what questions to *not* put it on. The proposed edit does neither so the edit should have been rejected as "lacks usage guidelines".

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me Seth. Where do I locate the guidelines for reviewing the tag wiki excerpts?

Comment: Right here @ElderGeek: http://askubuntu.com/help/tag-excerpts